# How to use up arrow key in shell script to get previous command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write my console with some basic functionalities.
Here is what I am doing.

```
function help()
{
        echo "add(a,b,...)"
}

function add()
{
arg=$(echo $1 | cut -d"(" -f2)
sum=0
for number in `echo ${arg} | sed -e 's/[,) ]\+/\n/g'` ; do
        sum=$(($sum + $number))
done
echo $sum
}

while true
do

echo -n "mycon@avi>>"
read command
opt=$(echo "$command" | cut -d"(" -f1)
case $opt in
"exit"|"q")
        exit
;;
"help")
        help
;;
"add")
        add $command
;;
esac
done
```

I am saving this file as `mycon`
when I run this script `./mycon`

```
mycon@avi>>add(2,3)
5
mycon@avi>>
```

Now in this moment when I am pressing up arrow key, I want to get the above `add(2,3)` command. what is the way to do this ??

Thank You

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash-only solution:

1. Change `read command` to `read -e command` so that bash will enable the readline library.
2. Add the command `history -s "$command"` to include the line read into the history.

Note that `read command` will delete trailing whitespace from the typed command before assigning the line to `command`, unless you invoke it with `IFS` set to the empty string. Also, `read` will normally treat backslashes as escape characters, which is usually undesirable; you can suppress that behaviour with the `-r` flag. Finally, you can get `read` to print the prompt, which will work better with readline, using the `-p` option. So your final sequence might look like this:

```
while IFS= read -e -p "mycon@avi>> " command; do
  history -s "$command"
  # ... process the command
done
```

(Using the `read` command as the condition in the while statement causes the while loop to terminate if the user enters an EOF character.)

For more information on `read` and `history`, use the built-in bash `help` command (`help read` / `help history`)

Comment: Thank You for the reply, but its not working according to my requirement, after changing `read command` to `read -e command` when I am pressing up arrow, it showing `./mycon` but I needed `add(2,3)`.

Comment: @avinashse: Indeed. You also need to add the line to the history. Edited the answer and added a couple of suggestions for improvements.